# How to redirect to admin page with middleware auth in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am struggling with this  for couple of days, and I can't find what I am doing wrong.

I created a login form. The routes are under group middleware auth. When I try to login it shows me that I am logged, but I am not redirected to my admin panel, I am returning to the login page.
I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the middleware but I don't know what I am dong wrong.

My routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/login','Admin\LoginController@index')->name('login');
Route::post('/admin/loginF','Admin\LoginController@loginF');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
   Route::get('/admin','Admin\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
   Route::get('/admin/logout',function(){
     Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/admin/login/');
   });
});
```

Login:
class LoginController extends Controller {

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function Index() {
    return view('admin.login');
}

public function loginF(Request $request) {

     $credentials = [
        'username' => $request['username'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
    ];

   if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
       return redirect("/admin");
   } else {   
   return Redirect::back()->withErrors("Error Login!");
   }
}
}
```

And in my DashboardController I have

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

EDIT:

This is the default, didn't change it

```
  class RedirectIfAuthenticated{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
           return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
   }
 }
```

Comment: So it's showing two redirects?  One to `admin` then to `login`?

Comment: No, it just return back to login page, even that he pass the login

Comment: Assuming you're not getting redirected back to Login with the "Error Login" error, maybe we need to see the code for your auth middleware?

Comment: If you're not getting a redirect to /admin in the http chain, it seems like your auth attempt is failing.

Comment: @Rich upload the middleware auth

Comment: I think that's your `guest` middleware rather than your `auth` middleware. But if you haven't changed your auth middleware then I'm thinking your login is failing and you're not actually being logged in. If you're keen to understand it, you could place trace `\Log::info('Got to point x')` throughout the steps you think are happening to figure out where the redirects are kicking in?

Answer (score 0):

I remember what i did in my case. I created a middleware and in which i checked the $guard variable.

`$this->middleware('LoggedIn:admin');` //is called in constructor of MyAdmin with which all other admin pages were extended.

Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() == false) {
          switch ($guard) {
            case 'client':
              return redirect('/Login');
              break;
            case 'vendor':
              return redirect('/Login');
              break;
            case 'employee':
              return redirect('/Login');
              break;
            case 'admin':
              $output = $this->EmployeeAccess($request);
              if($output['status'] == false){
                return redirect($output['link']);
              }
              break;
            default:
              return redirect('/');
              break;
          }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

On login page you should check

```
if($this->guard('admin')->check() === true) // then redirect to admin dashboard
```

for other users

```
 if($this->guard('user')->check() === true) // then redirect to  user dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

On your loginF method:

```
public function login()
{
    //check if auth passed, if so, redirect to dashboard
    if (Auth::check()) return redirect('/dashboard');

    //if failed, return view to login
    return view('login');
}
```

Comment: the problem is with the middleware, not with the auth